# Android: Stretch Widescreen Image to fill the whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Widescreen Image that i want to put into a horizontal scroll view, with it ftting the whole screen vertically(and letting me scroll horizontally) but it simply stays at half height and won't let me scale it higher (layout_height is set to "fill_parent").

I already thought about using the image in different source resolutions but i think i cannot cover all possible resolutions so that is not really an option i guess.

I also want to put buttons on specific locations onto that image and want them to move with the image if that is important.

Comment: use layout_height="match_parent" and scaleType="fitXY". I think this can solve your problem

Comment: awesome, thanks! I already tried scaleType but it did not work, i guess i was both setings that had to fit. Though i had to just adjustviewbounds="true" for it not to break the aspect ratio.

Comment: hm, that broke the width... That seems to be locked to 2 times my screen width... at least on my phone, the layout editor shows it in correct aspect ratio...

Comment: can you try to use layout_width="wrap_content" and scaleType to fitY ? (Also put the image under a horizontalscrollview) What is result

Comment: FitY does not exist, it is already under a horizontalscrollview and wraping_content: http://pastebin.com/WYTvKVDM